# PHP Twig rendering huge XML data

Tags: php, xml, twig

I'm looking for a way to leverage the power of twig templates for generating an XML file, but the contents of this file are huge.  I want to avoid having the contents of this XML file in-memory, so at the moment, it's being written to disk as it's generated.

To render the twig template with its contents, it requires the full data structure in memory to be passed in.

Is there any way to begin rendering data against a twig template with partial data, to avoid having to load all the contents to memory first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I believe that I have found a solution to this by overriding the `render()` method in the `Template.php` file.  The current render() method uses ob_start() which stores buffered output to memory, and that memory limit is configured in your ini file.  Once that memory has been exceeded, your output is dumped to the default stream, which can result in partial data.

By extending the default Template class and overriding the render method, you can specify an alternative to memory buffer storage such as php read-write streams (i.e. php://temp, php://fd).

Now, when instantiating your `Twig_Environment` object, simply pass your new template class in:

`$twig = new Twig_Environment(
new Twig_Loader_String,
['base_template_class' => 'My_Twig_Template']
);`

Comment: Do you have any code snipped for the My_Twig_Template how to use the read-write streams?

Comment: @Boris, I currently do not have a code snippet (I haven't had a chance to implement my solution). My idea was to extend the default template, and override any methods using the ob_start function. One possible solution would be to still use the ob_start function, but pass in a callback function. The callback function could be responsible for writing the buffer to file.